# ClassNotFound exception in jbpm + Spring integration

Tags: spring, integration, websphere, jbpm

All,
I am trying to get Spring + jbpm + JPA + JTA integration on websphere.

I have kept the jbpm.jar in the WEB-INF\lib directory.. still I keep getting this exception trace...

> [7/5/11 15:08:57:091 IST] 00000011
>   webapp        E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp
>   notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E:
>   Exception caught while initializing
>   context: {0}
>                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.jbpm.api.ProcessEngine    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFieldsImpl(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:550)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:798)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1707)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:380)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:731)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:616)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1122)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:610)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:725)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4582)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4760)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1271)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2043)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:439)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:382)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:653)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:615)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
>     at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
>     at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1332)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1225)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi.RMIConnectorService.invoke(RMIConnectorService.java:282)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:395)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:160)
>     at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:623)
>     at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:476)
>     at
>   com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:513)
>     at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1574)
>     at
>   com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2845)
>     at
>   com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2718)
>     at
>   com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:63)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jbpm.api.ProcessEngine    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:150)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:90)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:541)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
>     ... 73 more

is there anything special set-up in spring that needs to be done to find classes in classpath?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring requires nothing special to be done.

Since this is a web app, it might be that you need a higher-level class loader because that JAR is required by the app server itself.

There's a hierarchy of class loaders in app servers: bootstrap->server->application.  When you put a JAR in WEB-INF/lib it's picked up by the application class loader.  You might try putting the `org.jbpm.api.ProcessEngine` JAR in the server /lib and trying it again.

Comment: looks like that is the problem. I still am facing problems with other class not found exception. Trying to find out a better solution to this since I have a lot of libraries in my WEB-INF/lib folder. But this sure did help

Comment: Keep adding JARs until all the CNF exceptions go away.  It's painful, but guaranteed to be finite.